# How can I simply impute NA values in R using Amelia and then divide the data set into a data and training set in a 70:30 split?

Tags: r

I want to impute values from a data set (14 variables, 200 observations) and then split it into a 70% training data set and a 30% testing data set.

Every time I work with `Amelia` to impute I get different types of error messages. I'm looking for the simplest way to have `Amelia` impute this entire data set.

```
colnames(mydata) <- c("age", "sex", "cp", "trestbps", "chol", "fbs", "restecg", "thalach", "exang", "oldpeak", "slope", "ca", "thal", "num")

mydata <- subset(mydata, select=-c(ca,thal))
```

I also get this error and I'm unsure of what it means:

> Amelia Error Code:  36
>        The number of categories in the nominal variable 'chol' is greater than one-third of the observations.
>       Warning messages:
>       1: In amcheck(x = x, m = m, idvars = numopts$idvars, priors = priors,  :
>     The number of categories in one of the variables marked nominal has greater than 10 categories. Check nominal specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amelia checks to see if there are not too many categories in a variable. This is done by counting the unique occurrences of the variable and comparing this to one-third of the rows.

For example, if you have 300 rows of data and you have more than 100 unique values in your column (excluding NA's), amelia will return this error. Imputing on so many different values on so few records is almost impossible that you might as well fill in random values. Either think about whether or not you need this column, get more data, or see if you can find a way to fill in the missing data based on domain knowledge.

For more information on Amelia check the vignette, but if you want to read through the code, check the github page. You can find it [here](https://github.com/IQSS/Amelia). Especially the error code might be handy to read through (amcheck.r).

Splitting your data in 70/30 can be done in multiple ways. Two that I use are either:

```
library(caTools)
# set.seed for reproducibility.
set.seed(144) 
split <- sample.split(dataframe$"Variable to split on", SplitRatio = 0.7)
train <- subset(dataframe, split == TRUE)
test <- subset(dataframe, split == FALSE)
```

or

```
library(caret)
# set.seed for reproducibility.
set.seed(42)
split <- createDataPartition(y = dataframe$"Variable to split on", p=0.7, list=FALSE)
train <- dataframe[subtrain,]
test <- dataframe[-subtrain,]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @phiver, I appreicate it. I read through the vignette and the manual on Amelia and I got imputation to work, but still am unsure how to divide the data set into a training set and a testing set. I am hoping to have it randomly split into 70% for training data and 30% testing data and then find out what the p-value is for the test set. Sorry if this is confusing, I am trying to better understand my professor's requests myself. Thanks again for your help!